# Bizzare bug in Windows Forms with ToolStripContainer (I don't even know how to explain, so here's a video)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, toolstripcontainer

Well, here it is. Watch this video to see what happens:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9uA2qWm5JI&feature=youtu.be

Basically, I have a ToolStripContainer on my form, because I want to have a MenuStrip on top and ToolStripStatusLabel on bottom. Inside the center panel, I want to have control that takes up most of its space (Anchored Top Left Bottom Right) and two buttons (Anchored Bottom Right)

It fails ridiculously.

So, I arrange it all on this ToolStripContentPanel control. Buttons are almost touching the bottom of the form. Then I run my program and a wild blank space appears! There's now like 30 or so pixels between the buttons and the form! So the form in the designer and the form in the actual program don't match up!

It gets more ridiculous. If, in the designer, I undo, then it gets completely screwed up. Just watch the video.

What the hell is going on here?

PS: How to reproduce:

1) Create new WinForms solution

2) Add ToolStripContentPanel Control to Form, Dock = Fill

3) Add Button to ToolStripContentPanel, Anchor = Bottom Right

4) Resize Form

5) Undo

6) Observe the bug

Do I need to post the code VS 2010 generates in Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs files?

Comment: Not an uncommon problem when anchoring to the right or bottom.  Calculating the size of the control based on the original size of the window instead of the actual size.  This is a coding problem, we of course cannot see it.  A minimum repro is required to get help.

Comment: Could you explain please... what coding problem? You mean, there's problem in my code?

Comment: Yes, you must provide the code here if you want help with it.

Comment: You mean you need the code that VS 2010 generates? This bug is perfectly reproducable in several simple steps.

Comment: Repro'ed the undo part in 2010 and 2012... log a bug?